# How to store and remove a regex pattern at once?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group, regex-greedy

I want to know if is possible to do this without checking for the regex pattern twice.

I am on python 3

```
pp = re.search(r'(.)(.+)\1(.+)', word)
word = re.sub(r'(.)(.+)\1(.+)', '', word)
salv = pp.groups()
word + = salv[0] + salv[0] + inverse(salv[1]) + salv[2]
```

There first I look for the matches, and then I remove the matches, but I am looking for the same regex patter twice. And I feel it can be done other way.

So what I want to do is:

Match a pattern, remove that pattern, and concat what I matched on a different way.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input and expected output?

Comment: I just wanna remove the patern and store what ever it matches somewhere. If I just could remove a regex object... Because ``re.search`` returns an object.

Comment: So that would be a "no" in answer to my question?

Comment: I dont know what kind of example you want.

Comment: I though that was obvious: what's a typical value for `word`, and what should the resulting value of `word` be?

Comment: input: ``mmabacbc`` output: ``mmaaBcbc``. As I said, i dont think this is usefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub) method with a function as the value for its *repl* argument.

```
import re
word = 'mmabacbc'
print(re.sub(r'(.)(.+)\1(.+)', lambda m: m.group(1) * 2 + m.group(2).swapcase() + m.group(3), word))
```

**Output**:

```
mmaaBcbc
```

Test it online with [Rextester](https://rextester.com/TYGXV41521).

Answer (score 0):

you could modify your regex pattern to return what you are looking for without the extra steps:

```
#  here we unpack the object, into the first group and the rest
#   |                  here we match anything else and add to first group
#   v                                  v
word_replacement, *slav = re.search(r'(.*)(.)(.+)\1(.+)', word)
# now everything is set up the same
word_replacement += slav[0] + slav[0] + inverse(slav[1]) + slav[2]
```

you can also use `re.sub` with \g<group> tags:

```
word_replacement = re.sub('(.)(.+)\1(.+)', '\g<1>\g<1>\g<2>\g<3>', word)
```

not sure how to implement inverse *in the regex* though.

Comment: Inverse is just ``word[::-1].swapcase()``